# How to find out All tables names & columns list use by SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have 600 SSRS reports deployed into production. How can I get meta data information of reports? Things like which reports use which tables. If any reports use more than 1 table, I am trying to get all tables used by the report.

Is it possible to get such info? Please help me

Comment: Does this help? https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dbtechresource/2015/04/04/retrieve-ssrs-report-server-database-information/

Comment: @JacobH: Thanks Jacob, but i am looking for all table used by all reports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to change the '[http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/](http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition)**2016**/01/reportdefinition' bit to the appropriate year your SSRS is, otherwise you get 0 rows in results.

-- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0cbb8997-c54c-4de8-87e8-529dc6e2b017/extract-metadata-from-report-server-database?forum=sqlreportingservices

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ( DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner' AS rd )
SELECT ReportName  = name
    ,DataSetName  = x.value('(@Name)[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') 
   ,DataSourceName = x.value('(Query/DataSourceName)[1]','VARCHAR(250)')
   ,CommandText  = x.value('(Query/CommandText)[1]','VARCHAR(250)')
   ,Fields   = df.value('(@Name)[1]','VARCHAR(250)')
   ,DataField  = df.value('(DataField)[1]','VARCHAR(250)')
   ,DataType  = df.value('(rd:TypeName)[1]','VARCHAR(250)')
   --,ConnectionString = x.value('(ConnectionProperties/ConnectString)[1]','VARCHAR(250)')
 FROM ( SELECT C.Name,CONVERT(XML,CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),C.Content)) AS reportXML
      FROM ReportServer.dbo.Catalog C
     WHERE C.Content is not null
      AND C.Type = 2
   ) a
 CROSS APPLY reportXML.nodes('/Report/DataSets/DataSet') r ( x )
 CROSS APPLY x.nodes('Fields/Field') f(df) 
ORDER BY name
```

Comment: links are broken need to explain answers also

Comment: Hi v8-E I've edited the post but please note the first "link" isn't supposed to be a link and it is actually an XML schema reference. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate the data in ReportServer.dbo.Catalog to pull out the XML for each RDL. Then if all your tables begin with a schema name you can probably perform a regex on the XML (or the dataset queries within the XML) to extract the table names. It likely is going to be messy. If you don’t use a two or three part table name (Database.schema.table or schema.table) this may be hard to write a regex against. Perhaps there is a tool that can extract table names from raw queries? In which case you can extract the queries from the Catalog table without too much effort.

On mobile device right now but I can provide the Catalog table extraction query if you think it will be helpful (I use it in production to search for table names...not extract all table names).